# Borland C++ BCB 5 - EAccessViolation DynamicArray Array too large

Tags: c++, memory, bpl, c++builder-5

I am using BCB 5 and I have a DynamicArray that works perfectly under normal conditions, but recently i have been forced to use it for a large dataset(About 7000 items) and my exception handler throws this EAccessViolation. This happens after:

```
try
{
    sz++;
    Recon.Length = (sz + 1);
}
```

And when i checked Recon.Length = 4606

I have increased the Heap Max Size to the maximum on the linker option but i still get this error.

Is there another way to increase the memory available to the application

Comment: Why not use a compiler that has been updated in the last 10 years? Gcc and Microsoft compilers are available for free, and they can both produce 64-bit code so you can get as much memory as there is in the machine.

Comment: Problem is this is a legacy application that was designed and customized using BCB 5 and I am not if it will work or compile with those compilers but i guess i will have to try that as a last resort.

Comment: What model are you compiling it as?

Comment: @MatsPetersson not 10 but ~13 years. I looked at my bcb.exe and bcc32.exe - they was created at 07 Aug 2000 =)

Comment: So it hasn't been updated in the last 10 years! My point wasn't exactly how old bcc is, but the fact that it isn't modern by any reasonable meaning (I'm sure if it was some sort of large scale industrial equipment, being 10+ years old would be considered modern, but not in a compiler).

Comment: By the way, 4600 elements seems quite a low number to "run out of memory" at. Are you running this as a DOS application? If so, is there a BC option for compiling it as a Win32 application? I haven't used Borland compiler(s) for the last 18 years, so if you excuse me if my memory of options isn't quite fresh...

Comment: What data type is `Recon` holding? How large is 1 instance of that data type?  How much memory does 4606+ times that byte size add up to? A dynamic array is contigious in memory, so every time you set the `Length` property, the RTL has to allocate a new memory block of the new size, copy the existing values to it, and then free the original memory block.  Eventually, the array is going to grow large enough that the RTL will not be able to locate enough contigious memory to allocate new arrays with.

Comment: You should consider installing [FastMM](http://fastmm.sourceforge.net) or other 3rd party memory manager, they do a lot better job of managing memory allocations than Borland's stock memory manager does (FYI, Borland MM was dropped and replaced by FastMM in a later BCB version).